# PHP Regex - Replace text not contained in quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to rewrite plain text search queries to match the internal format used by our search engine, and I'd like to use a bit of regex to replace certain words, but only when the original text is not encapsulated by double quotes. Here's what I mean:

- `rock from adelaide` would become `rock location:adelaide`
- `beep "rock from adelaide" boop` would remain `beep "rock from adelaide" boop`
- `find me some rock from "adelaide"` would become `find me some rock location:"adelaide"`
- `is there "any rock from adelaide please", thanks` would remain `is there "any rock from adelaide please", thanks`

I'm such a regex noob and no matter how much I read and research, I just can't figure out the solution here. I can do a search and replace on the word `from` easily enough, but only matching outside quotes is completely beyond me.

This is what I have so far, but obviously it's not working:

```
<?php
  $pattern = '%(*ANY)(.*?(")(?(2).*?")(.*?))*?from %s';
  $replace = '\1location:'; 
  $subject = 'find me some rock from adelaide but not "rock from perth"';
  print preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $subject);
?>
```

The expected output is:

`find me some rock location:adelaide but not "rock from perth"`

The actual output is:

`find me some rock location:adelaide but not "rock location:perth"`

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to replace words that are NOT BETWEEN double quotes. So, when we explode the string, the even indexes of the array would be our target (and 0 also). What we need is to create loop which will skip 2 indexes and use `str_replace()` in there. Would be something like this:

```
$test = '"rock from perth" xxxxxxx "afjakdhfa" find me some rock from adelaide but not ';
$array = explode('"', $test);
$count = count($array);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i+=2)
{
    $array[$i] = str_replace('from', 'location:', $array[$i]);
}
$test = implode('"', $array);
echo $test;
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly, I really appreciate your help. Although, for the sake of having the knowledge, I'm still definitely interested to know whether or not there's a regex pattern that would do the same thing.

Comment: Will be hard since the regex pattern won't know if this string is between or not. From the `$test` variable: `"rock from perth"` and `" xxxxxxx "` have double quotes between but xxxxxxx is not actually between :) If there is a way I would be surprised and amazed at the same time.